# “Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function” in backbone application view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'am trying to run my js application in browser, but when i do, i get this error in console:

“Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function” app.js:18

I have read and tried other answers to similar problem, but with no success.

The code with the error line 18:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: $("#todoapp"),

statsTemplate: _.template($('#stats-template').html()),

events: {
"keypress #new-todo":  "createOnEnter",
    "click #clear-completed": "clearCompleted",
    "click #toggle-all": "toggleAllComplete"
},

initialize: function() {

  this.input = this.$("#new-todo");
  this.allCheckbox = this.$("#toggle-all")[0];

  this.listenTo(Todos, 'add', this.addOne); //the line with the error
  this.listenTo(Todos, 'reset', this.addAll);
  this.listenTo(Todos, 'all', this.render);

  this.footer = this.$('footer');
  this.main = $('#main');

      Todos.fetch();
},

render: function() {
      var done = Todos.done().length;
      var remaining = Todos.remaining().length;

      if (Todos.length) {
        this.main.show();
        this.footer.show();
        this.footer.html(this.statsTemplate({done: done, remaining: remaining}));
      } else {
        this.main.hide();
        this.footer.hide();
      }

      this.allCheckbox.checked = !remaining;
    },

addOne: function(todo) {
      var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
      this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
    },

addAll: function() {
      Todos.each(this.addOne, this);
    },

createOnEnter: function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
      if (!this.input.val()) return;

      Todos.create({title: this.input.val()});
      this.input.val('');
    },

clearCompleted: function() {
      _.invoke(Todos.done(), 'destroy');
      return false;
    },

toggleAllComplete: function () {
      var done = this.allCheckbox.checked;
      Todos.each(function (todo) { todo.save({'done': done}); });
    }

});
```

Here is my collection.js code:

```
var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Todo,
localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("todos-backbone"),

done: function(){
return this.where({done: true});
},

remaining: function(){
return this.without.apply(this, this.done());
},

nextOrder: function(){
if (!this.length) return 1;
return this.last().get('order')+1;
},

comparator: 'order'

});

var Todos = new TodoList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade your Backbone version if you want to use `listenTo`. From the [fine ChangeLog](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog):

> **0.9.9** — *Dec. 13, 2012*
>
> - Added *listenTo* and *stopListening* to Events. They can be used as inversion-of-control flavors of `on` and `off`, for convenient unbinding of all events an object is currently listening to. `view.remove()` automatically calls `view.stopListening()`.

The `listenTo` method showed up in Backbone 0.9.9 but you're using 0.9.1.

Read the ChangeLog and upgrade your Backbone version.

Comment: When i add the newest backbone version, and run my code, i sitll get this error, but now it points to the backbone.js file and some random line. Got  any idea what this is about?

Comment: Is `Todos` defined? You really should be passing that to view as `new AppView({ collection: todos })` and then reference it as `this.collection` inside the view. You should also say `el: '#todoapp'` instead of `el: $("#todoapp")` to avoid order problems.

Answer (score 0):

this.listenTo(Todos, 'add', this.addOne);

You are using the Todos as an object that references to collection but the object for the collection in neither passed nor created in the view.

If you want to pass

```
var mycollection = new Todos();
new AppView({ myCollection: mycollection});
```

Since we are passing a key value we can fetch it back in view like

```
this.myCollection.add(model) or
this.myCollection.reset(); //to reset the collection
```

If you want to create a object for collection ,you can directly like the same way

```
var mycollection = new Todos();
```

Collections callback functions can be defined inside collection itself.This will help in reusing the function over multiple views .

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and after a few looks I realized that I misspelled the name of the element when i was initializing:

```
  this.allCheckbox = this.$("#toggle-all")[0];
```

So, check the name of the elements in your html

Answer (score -1):

Quite sure your problem is not on that line, but rather:

```
this.input = this.$("#new-todo");
this.allCheckbox = this.$("#toggle-all")[0];
```