# Attaching a Backbone.js event to a view based on the model attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone.js. Basically, I have a model attribute 'modified'. I simply want to check if its value is true and update the view accordingly. I have tried something like this in the view.

```
  this.model.on("change:modified", function() {
                        self.$el.show();
                });
```

or

```
   this.model.on("modified:true", function() {
                        self.$el.show();
                });
```

I have checked that on using console.log(this.model), it contains 'modified' as one of the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

```
this.listenTo(this.model, "change:modified", function(){
          self.$el.show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried using `listenTo`', but I get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: this.listenTo is not a function`. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554828/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-in-backbone-application-view) tells me that probably its a Backbone version problem. I am working on a big project so cannot upgrade the backbone version. What else can I do? Also, if I can explicitly compare the value to 'true' instead of the 'change' event, that would be great.

Comment: can you check the value of "this" at that line?